# Import styles directly from tailwindCSS config file

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a react application built with create-react-app v5 and I am using tailwindCSS v3.

My project's root directory is "./src" and tailwindCSS configuration file is at "./" (one directory before src).

```
./tailwind.config.js
```

I'm trying to import the file using this:

theme.tsx file

```
//@ts-ignore
import resolveConfig from "tailwindcss/resolveConfig";
import tailwindConfig from "../tailwind.config.js";

const config = resolveConfig(tailwindConfig);
const theme: any = config.theme;
export default theme;
```

Since tailwindCSS v3, I can't move the tailwind config file from the root directory.
The command above works but only if the file is inside "./src" and I can't place it there, so I get the following error:

> Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../tailwind.config.js
> which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports
> outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/,
> or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

How can I import tailwindCSS styles directly from the config file? what I want to be able to do is to style elements without the classNames, I want to get the values directly from the config file in order to do something like this:

```
<div>
   <p style={{color: theme.colors.blue}}>Blue Text</p>
</div>
```

Is there a solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to specify the custom configuration location as shown here? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#using-a-different-file-name

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes I did - in create-react-app v5 it doesn't work yet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced the same issue. So, I created one more tailwind.config inside src and exported as module from there.

**File structure:**

tailwind.config.js

```
const tailwindConfig = require("./src/tailwind.config");

module.exports = tailwindConfig;
```

src/tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = { 
  content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

src/tailwind-theme.js

```
import resolveConfig from "tailwindcss/resolveConfig";
const tailwindConfig = require("./tailwind.config");

const config = resolveConfig(tailwindConfig);
const theme = config.theme;
export default theme;
```

src/index.js

```
import theme from "tailwind-theme";

<div>
  <p style={{color: theme.colors.blue}}>Blue Text</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: I have issue with TS:
Trying to print colors with "console.log(theme?.colors?.blue)" it did logged but I got error:
Property 'blue' does not exist on type 'ResolvableTo<RecursiveKeyValuePair<string, string>>'.
  Property 'blue' does not exist on type '(utils: PluginUtils) => RecursiveKeyValuePair<string, string>'.ts(2339)